# glib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, glib, locate

I tried installing gtk and glib using

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

but locate glib.h does not return any path for glib
results of locate glib.h are

```
$ locate glib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/libjpeg/jpeglib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtimageformats/src/3rdparty/jasper/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_jpeglib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/base/message_loop/message_pump_glib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb-glib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libjpeg/jpeglib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/libjpeg_turbo/jpeglib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/pdfium/third_party/libjpeg/jpeglib.h
/home/asus/Qt5.8.0/5.8/Src/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/ui/events/platform/x11/x11_event_source_glib.h
/usr/include/reglib/reglib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-36-generic/include/config/blk/dev/bsglib.h
```

using updatedb solves this error.

But I get 1 more error
fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory

I think it is related to glib also

I got the answer `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` flag solves this

Answer (score 6):

Add `-I/usr/include/glib-2.0` to your compiler command line (check the path of course). You will need to amend your makefile probably

Comment: It looks as if the question is about the `locate` command and not about `gcc`.

Comment: Interesting downvotes.  @alk I had this "problem" some time ago and unfortunately updating the database (I was same smart as you) did not help. Maybe now it is sorted. So this workaround was the quickest solution.

Comment: Running `updatedb` would help `locate` only, sure. It won't help GCC. But well, the question is about `locate`, isn't it? I removed my downvote, BTW.

Comment: BTW^2: doing `find / -name glib.h` might still be faster then running `updatedb`.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand something but usually .h files are used during the programming and compiling (of course I can be wrong). I don't think that he needs it to print and use as a wallpaper or maybe a giftwrap.

Comment: You'll never know ... ;-)

Comment: @alk :) BTW ls -d /usr/include/g* is even quicker

Comment: This uses "local" knowledge, not fair ... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

> but `locate glib.h` does not return any path for **glib**

You might want to update `locate`'s database (by running `updatedb`), or wait until tomorrow ... ;-)